# How to use switch functions to check if the file name conatins ABC

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

I have created a logic app where I need to check if my file name contains "ABC" then i need to copy file and paste it in ABC folder Azure else need to check if my file name contains "ZYX" then paste it in ZYX folder in Azure.

In switch function its giving me an error.

> "The execution of template action 'Switch' failed: The result of the evaluation of 'scope' action expression '@body('Get_file_content')' is not valid. It is of type 'Object' but is expected to be a value of type 'String, Integer'." [Image1]

or if I am trying to use 2 conditions in parallel branch its giving me the below error.

![Image2]

I also tried conditions, if the file name contains "ABC" then copy paste in ABC folder if false then i tried using another conditions inside the false command.

Also, follow up question would be if I have multiple file name with ABC then can I merge and place it in one file and paste that in ABC folder in Azure Blob

Image using switch function:

[image]

Image Conditions using parallel branch:

![Image Conditions using parallel branch]
[image]

Attaching the latest screenshot with your suggestion.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJFKM.png)

i just tried using one and its giving me the error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfPiA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Reason for the error** : You cannot pass`file content` as a condition check in the switch Connector.

**Solution**: In order to get the desired output as described above you need to pass the file name as a condition check in switch control. As we receive the File Name from the SharePoint connector as base64 format we need to decode it to string using `**base64ToString(FileName)**` to compare the folder names present in the containers/blob.

Here is the code view of the logic app based on the above-discussed requirement.
[image]

> Also, follow up question would be if I have multiple file name with
> ABC then can I merge and place it in one file and paste that in ABC
> folder in Azure Blob

Using the above flow, merging of files is not possible since each file is saved in different extensions but override of the file takes place in the blob if you are uploading or updating the same file.

For more information about merging of files using Logic app you can refer this [BLOG](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Community-Blog/Merge-SharePoint-documents-using-Microsoft-Flow-or-Azure-Logic/ba-p/247814).

**UPDATED ANSWER**

Before Comparing the string/ Filename you can use 'Compose' before the 'Condition' Connector and convert the string into lower case.

```
toLower(base64ToString(triggerOutputs()['headers']['x-ms-file-name-encoded']))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Swethakandikonda-MT,

Thanks a lot, i tried and it worked, but the concerns is i have many files which contains same name. example, i have sales data from different country and i have asked them to upload it in SharePoint containing the "sales" name at the end of the file, in this case i need to give if my file name contains "Sales" instead of equals, Any idea for this.

Comment: @NageshShastry As per your requirement, I have updated the answer accordingly. Would suggest you take a look and revert back if you need any further assistance.

Comment: @Swethakandikinda-MT, i honestly appreciate you for supporting above and beyond.
in fact i was waiting for your response so that i can try the methods.
one question on your updated answer
how do i mention else if multiple times, 
for example if the files contains ABC then its should paste it in ABC folder in Blob else if its ZYX its should paste under ZXY folder in Blob else if HIJ then it should fall under HIJ folder.
From your Comment i can see only on conditions.
Thanks for the support and Help.

Comment: @NageshShastry One workaround you can do is that you can add a parallel branch and mention the conditions according to your requirements. https://i.imgur.com/tAZrrAF.png

Comment: I tried the parallel Branch as well, but its of no use.
i am unable to figure out the reason.

Comment: @NageshShastry try it in this way https://i.imgur.com/uCspMMP.png

Comment: I am Trying the same thing and only one of the conditions is getting fetched, others are getting skipped.

Comment: are you trying parallel branching like in this picture https://i.imgur.com/uCspMMP.png

Comment: Yes, i doing exactly same. I am unable to edit the post as it says full

Comment: @NageshShastry Can you please tell me what are all the conditions you are trying? So that it will be helpful for reproducing the problem

Comment: i have add the screenshot in your comments.

Comment: for one conditions i want the file name which ever contains NPS it should fetch, in that case i wont be able to give exact file name right?

Comment: @NageshShastry Can you try to compare without giving spaces with the same 'Contains' operation i.e.. Instead of Driver Grouping just try giving Driver.  I tried the exact same thing in the standard logic app and found that it is working fine when there are no spaces given while comparing

Comment: are you using multiple conditions?

Comment: yes @NageshShastry, I'm using the same flow as before but just avoiding the spaces

Comment: @NageshShastry Did your issue got resolved?

Comment: I am trying exactly the same way, I have 4 conditions out of which only 1 conditions is getting passed everytime. Other wise its giving this error 
"
ActionBranchingConditionNotSatisfied. The execution of template action 'Create_blob_(V2)' skipped: the branching condition for this action is not satisfied."

Comment: is there any possible way where i can demonstrate this with you

Comment: @NageshShastry I just checked your previous screenshots. Can you make `is equal to` to `contains` and try again once without any spaces in if condition.

Comment: @swethakandikonda_MT, i have done that as well and failed attached is the screenshot

Comment: i am guessing my blob is not correct. Below is the code for the same

Comment: @NageshShastry Also in the if condition You are converting into lower case and comparing with uppercase 'NPS' that may also be one of the places where it is failing

Comment: @NageshShastry Can you please check whether you are connecting to the storage account with the right access key and name.

Comment: it was working for one conditions and i am using the same for all the conditions.
Can we connect through Hangout so that i can show at once please.
My Mail id is Nagesh.shastry1@gamil.com
This will be very helpful if you can help me to solve this

Comment: what should be inside the Get file content File identifier, I am using file identifier itself, is it correct

Comment: yes @NageshShastry

Comment: Yes yes, your answer was so helpful, Thanks a lot